# Wordpress CRED/CRUD unable to modify $item array

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am getting the following message when I run this on my wordpress crud/cred form: There was an error while updating item.

The issue is when I try to modify the array with `'name' => $item['name']`

It seems to work with `'id' => $item['id']` but it doesn't seem to accept my custom code.

Note there is an entry in the sql table for `'name'`

```
$result = $wpdb->update($mytablename, $item, array(
    'id' => $item['id'], 
    'name' => $item['name'],
));
$item['name'] = 'test';

if ($result) {
    $message = __('Item was successfully updated', 'custom_table_name');
} else {
    $notice = __('There was an error while updating item', 'custom_table_name');
}
```